# Iterate through Data Frame, group columns with Pandas GroupBy.nunique, and export grouped Data Frame columns to multiple .xlsx files

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have an excel file with over 300k records, and I'm trying to select out smaller data subsets into separate .xlsx files based on the column type "Executive Office" each record is listed under. There are 10 different office types, and I'm able to see that `df.groupby('Executive Office').nunique()` correctly displays this count.

I know that there is something in the loop that's not reading the results of my group by correctly, but I can't quite understand what is happening when it iterates through the Data Frame.

```
df = pd.read_excel(file.xlsx)
execGroups = df.groupby('Executive Office').nunique()

#for-loop intending to separate out employees by each individual executive group and export to .xlsx
for name, group in execGroups:
    df.to_excel('C:/filepath{}.xlsx'.format(name), index = False)
    print('Executive Group Files created')
```

My error is:

> for name, group in execGroups:
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Is this error appearing because I don't have a list or dictionary defined for the executive office types, and/or am I not understanding the use of keys correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because there is just one variable in execGroups. You are trying to get two : name,group..

Try this :

```
for i in list(df['Executive Office'].unique()):
    tempdf=df.loc[df['Executive Office']=i]
    tempdf.to_excel('C:/filepath{}.xlsx'.format(i), index = False)
```

Comment: Howdy NabMe. It looks like this gives me a syntax error for the 'equals  i' sign in `tempdf=df.loc[df['Executive Office']=i]`. Is there something else I can try?

Comment: Hi, I just typed code quickly... it should be '==' instead of '='

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Would there be a way to add another argument to the line `tempdf=df.loc[df['Executive Office']==i]` to further specify the week? as in another one of the column names is called 'Week' - specifically the week of '12/13 - 12/19'